# DRF Serializer sets provided field to None

Tags: django, validation, date, serialization, django-rest-framework

i'm currently at a project where i want to test the validation of my serializers. I run into the problem that the Serializers set's a provided field to `None` in the process of validation which does not seem reasonable to me.

Here more details (shorted for simplicity):

models.py :

```
class Contract(models.Model):
    start_date = models.DateField()
    end_date = models.DateField()
```

serializers.py:

```
class ContractSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Contract
        fields = "__all__"

    def validate(self, attrs):
        """
        Object-level validation.
        Here we validate : start_date is, timewise, prior to end_date
        :param attrs:
        :return:
        """

        if not attrs["start_date"] < attrs["end_date"]:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Sample Error Message.")

        return attrs
```

I use pytest for testing and pytest-django.

My conftest.py :

```
from pytz import datetime


@pytest.fixture
def valid_contract_json():
    start_date = datetime.date(2019, 1, 1)
    end_date = datetime.date(2019, 1, 31)

    data = {
        "start_date": start_date,
        "end_date": end_date,
    }

    return data
```

My test(s) looks like :

test_serializers.py:

```
from app.serializers import ContractSerializer

class TestContractSerializer:
    def test_validation(self, valid_contract_json):
        ContractSerializer(data=valid_contract_json).is_valid(raise_exception=True)
```

When running this Test it fails and show the following message:

> TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'datetime.date' and 'NoneType'

I did some investigation on this:

1. Comment the validate method out.
2. Modify Test to :

   ```
   def test_validation(self, valid_contract_json):

       pprint.pprint(valid_contract_json)        

       seri = ContractSerializer(data=valid_contract_json).is_valid(raise_exception=True)
       # Serialization won't throw exception now
       pprint.pprint(seri.data)
   ```

This way i get the actual output of the data before handing it to the Serializer and the data prepared by the Serializer.

The output is:

```
{
 'start_date': datetime.date(2019, 1, 1),
 'end_date': datetime.date(2019, 1, 31),
}

{
 'start_date': '2019-01-01',
 'end_date': None,
}
```

I also checked if the end_date is already None when `validate()` is called.
The answer is YES.

So my Question is : Why does the serializer here perform as expected with `start_date` but fail with `end_date` ?

Could this be a hidden cache problem with pytest ?
**EDIT:**

I tried `pytest --cache-clear` which did not solve the problem so i suspect that it is not a chache problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found out why the error occured.

The problem was neither with pytest nor with the provided fixture or the process of data aggregation.

The Problem is that i had a field level validation as follows :

```
def validate_end_date(self, end_date):

    if end_date.day not in (14, monthrange(end_date.year, end_date.month)[1]):
        raise serializers.ValidationError()
```

As you can see this was poorly implemented by me as i forgot to return the field value if the validation passes. In this manner the Field Value became `None`.

Lesson learned : When implementing field level validation do **NOT** forget to return the initial value.

--> Methid afterwards:

```
def validate_end_date(self, end_date):

    if end_date.day not in (14, monthrange(end_date.year, end_date.month)[1]):
        raise serializers.ValidationError()
    return start_date
```